# Two solutions with iterations, one using pointers other for loop, but pointer has better time complexity- why?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing a solution for: https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/

Here is my code:

```
def maxSlidingWindow(nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
    res = []
    for i in range(len(nums)-k+1): 
        for j in range(i+k-1,len(nums)):                        
            res.append(max(nums[i:j+1]))
            break      
    return res
```

This solution runs into a `time-out error`.

I have found another similar solution, but it doesn't run into the same time-out error:

```
    def get_max(nums, start, end):
        answer = -2**31
        for i in range(start, end+1):
            answer = max(answer, nums[i])
        return answer
    
    def maxSlidingWindow( nums, k):
        start,end = 0,k-1
        result = []
        while end < len(nums) and len(nums):
            result.append(self.get_max(nums, start, end))
            start, end = start+1, end+1
        return result
```

While the two solutions do the same thing- I want to understand why mine runs into a time-out error. I do understand that having two for-loops; one inside another is very inefficient, but for the code above, we are breaking out of the inner for-loop immediately after each iteration of the outer for loop, so I didn't see this slowing things down (and so what is causing the time-complexity to be different?)

Comment: The issue might be the list slice, which has to create a new `list` object to pass to `max`. The other solution only indexes the list.

Comment: I see let me review this, but am I right in saying that the double for-loop does not make the first solution slower than the second?

Comment: And sorry, why would slicing or creating new lists slow things down? I can see it affecting the space complexity, but not time?

Comment: Because it takes time to create the list and copy the references over from the original list. It's not simply a 'window" into the original list.

Comment: okay, I never knew that before. Thanks!

Comment: The asymptotic time complexity would be the same, true, but it still takes time to build the list.

Comment: (I wonder how `max(nums[x] for x in range(i, j+1))` would compare. no new list is created, but using the iterator protocol might slow it down as well.)

Comment: The "for j..." loop looks wrong. It can only ever do, at most, one iteration.

Comment: Both solutions are not very efficient though.  It is not necessary to iterate the entire window for every window. You could use a monotonic queue and improve performance.

Comment: @DarkKnight, but that is exactly what I want/need it to do? Because for each element 'I', I only want to compare it once with k elements

Comment: @schwobaseggl, could you explain more? Because I saw the solution with queue online, but I couldn't think of how this could help the time complexity at all? We store each window in a queue?

Comment: No, the q represents the window, but every element gets added and removed from that q only once while the max element is always at the front of the q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient way uses a monotonic queue. I tried to make this as explanatory as possible :)

```
def maxSlidingWindow(nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
    d = deque()  # keep this monotonic
    
    def eat(i):
        # kick from the back all indeces of smaller numbers that came before
        while d and nums[d[-1]] <= nums[i]:  
            d.pop()
        d.append(i)
    
    def spit(i):
        # kick index out the front if still present
        if i == d[0]:  
            d.popleft()
    
    for i in range(k-1):
        # first, fill sliding window except one
        eat(i)
        
    def slide():
        # then: consume next slot -> yield max -> eject last
        for i in range(k-1, len(nums)):
            eat(i)
            yield nums[d[0]]
            spit(i-k+1)
    
    return list(slide())
```

`d` represents the window, but every element gets added and removed from `d` only once while the max element is always at the front.

Comment: Thanks, is this O(n)? for time

Comment: Yes, it is. Every num in nums (or rather its index) gets appended exactly once and popped at most once. The window max is found in O(1) as there is no iteration of the window. The naive approaches you posted are `O(n*k)` because of the repeated window iteration (max [+ slice]). Here, you make use of the fact that you already have information about most of the window each time from the previous rounds.

Comment: How about the complexity of the second solution I posted, is it also O(n*k)? Because there is no creation of lists there, only pointers/indexes used- so would it be O(n)?

Comment: I've spent days trying to understand the above, and I get most of it except for "nums[d[-1]] <= nums[i]:  " ; why are we doing nums[d[-1]], I can't see the connection of taking the last element of the deque(), and then looking at the corresponding element in nums- why do we do this??